# Array filled with variables not updating

Tags: android, arrays

Easy question I guess the answer will be very simple.

CODE:
init variables

```
public static float AGREE = 1;
public static float DISAGREE = 1;
float values[] = { AGREE, DISAGREE };
```

changing value of variables and then calling them:

```
AGREE = 10;
DISAGREE = 1;
Log.d("Agree or disagree pressed", "AgreeValue" + values[0] + " DisagreeValue" +   
values[1]);
```

When I logged out AGREE and DISAGREE value it was 10 and 1 but when I log values[0] and values [1] it logs out 1 and 1. It happens even if I call log right in onCreate method (so nothing before is executed). Why it is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you change the variables, they are not the same which you added first 
in the float value[] array.
Once you create an array, the array have his own vars.

you must change it directly with :

```
values[0] = 10;
values[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't Change value of array once you initialized array.